# Swift playground on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm learning Swift at the moment and I'm hoping to test out some ideas with `CMMotionManager`. Specifically I want to graph the output of the magnetometer.

Is this possible with Playgrounds? Ie., can I write code that will be run on the real attached iPhone or iPad (not the simulator), but see graphs and results displayed on the Mac that I am developing on?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the simple answer is "no".

Quoting a transcript of [**Swift Playgrounds** – WWDC 2014 Session 408](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/408):

> So anything which requires a device will not be supported with Playgrounds.

I'll leave this question open though. Perhaps there is a tidy way to have some code running on the phone that is sending data to an Xcode playground were I can work with it further.

Comment: Swift Playgrounds on iPad was demoed at WWDC2016 by using the iPad's accelerometer.